# Nice tool for creating slide-show using HTML5, CSS3

Tags: html, css, slideshow

Is there any nice tool or plugin available to create slide-show presentation using HTML5 and CSS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one i know that is designed for presentations:

http://slides.html5rocks.com/

http://studio.html5rocks.com/#Deck

Comment: Is there any library/plugin behind that presentation.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I'll explore more into that.

Answer (score 2):

I use http://html5slides.pageforest.com for all my presentations !
It's pretty simple and yet powerful.

Answer (score 2):

[reveal-js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/) is cool!

Support chrome/firefox/opera/safari.

iOS is also supported.

Comment: There is also now a web UI to create reveal-js slide presentations: http://rvl.io

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of jquery plugins for doing this sort of thing just google 'jquery gallery' or 'jquery slideshow' and you will have plenty of examples